# How to disable loop for 1 image using LoopViewPager library android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using [LoopViewPager](https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager) for looping images in ViewPager, it works fine with any number of images by creating 2 extra dummy items, it even loops for 1 image which i want to disable how to do this using the same library ?

I tried disabling touch `onTouchEvent()` when items are 1, but no use. Have anyone achieved this ?